# How can I get value from code behind for a confirm dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem, I'm trying to get a value from code behind for using it in a confirm dialog. but I can't retrieve it, I don't know why.
I'm using a confirm dialog for my creation button (this show a div content):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear]").removeAttr("onclick");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Confirmacion",
            width: 350,
            height: 220,
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: "Yes",
                    text: "Si",
                    click: function () {
                        $("[id*=imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear]").attr("rel", "Borrar");
                        $("[id*=imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear]").click();
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "No",
                    text: "No",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        $("[id*=imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("rel") != "Borrar") {
                $('#dialog2').dialog('open');
                return false;
            } else {
                __doPostBack(this.name, '');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

What I want is show in this confirm dialog is show to user info what is doing, thats the requirement.

In my code I have (until now just testing):

```
public string custom = "";
protected void Lotes_Crear_Individual(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    custom = "I want this f****ng value on my dialog";
    // button action 
}
```

This is my button, and I need that my div content shows my custom value:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear" runat="server"
                                                ImageUrl="~/images/CajaLlenar.png" OnClick="Lotes_Crear_Individual" />
                                            <div id="dialog2" style="display: none">
                                                Agregar grupo de lotes?
                                                <asp:Label Text='<%#custom %>' runat="server" />
                                                <label for="Name"><%#custom %></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value='<%#custom %>' />
                                            </div>
```

I was testing in different ways, different controls... but It doesn't works

Comment: Are you trying to get this input id=name by using this.name? Cuz that's not right. Can you clarify where you're trying to get the <%#custom %> value to be used?

Comment: thanks Nikki.. I was triying in different ways, I just take for this post one of them,   it does not work either

Comment: Do you call DataBind() on that asp:label and did you try `<%=custom%>` on those non-server controls? Also consider to make that `custom` field a property: `public string custom {get;set;}`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're  trying to do. Yeah, make that a property, and use `<%# this.custom %>`

Comment: Thanks a lot... I declared custom field property, example: public string CodigoCaja { get { return _codigoCaja; } } and with <%=CodigoCaja%> and in aspx I can retrieve that value, BUT in my case, OnClick or OnClientClick don't fire this, this only works for load page or with a dropdownlist postback

Answer (score 0):

try using session

```
protected void Lotes_Crear_Individual(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["custom"] = "I want this f****ng value on my dialog";
    // button action 
}
```

and then retrieve here: i changed <%# to <%= because you are just simply try to output a text

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn_LotCrePL_Crear" runat="server"
                                                ImageUrl="~/images/CajaLlenar.png" OnClick="Lotes_Crear_Individual" />
                                            <div id="dialog2" style="display: none">
                                                Agregar grupo de lotes?
                                                <asp:Label Text='<%= Session("custom") %>' runat="server" />
                                                <label for="Name"><%= Session("custom") %></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value='<%= Session("custom") %>' />
                                            </div>
```